# Please help Identify Italian frame

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image][image][image][image]

59-60cm frame, Sun Tour Superbe Pro Brakes, Shifter, front and rear derailleur, and complete Crank is Sun Tour Superbe Pro. Campagnolo head set and pedals. Cinelli 64-40 handle bar and Cinelli stem. It's an Italian make I'm sure. Serial number on the BB is BMZ 09 is all I can make out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The bike's a beauty. :)

Comment: Cotterless cranks, downtube shifters, 6-speed rear.  This lobbies for 1980-ish.  But those EYEtalians have always been weird, so the date is a bit harder to pin down.

Comment: That one piece aluminum handlebar stem should be checked to make sure it's not one of the "death stems."

Answer (score 3):

BMZ presumably stands for [Biemmezeta](http://www.classicrendezvous.com/Italy/Biemmezeta.htm), an Italian manufacturer from near Milan who did a lot of contract manufacturing for a lot of places (e.g. [Performance Cycles](https://blog.performancebike.com/2011/03/25/flashback-friday-revisited-performance-campione/)) as well as sold bicycles under their own brand. More details on your location may help narrow down the bike's pedigree.

As Daniel R Hicks estimates the date of the bike in the comments, it should be noted that BMZ was popular in the 1980s.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your bike is actually an italian frame built by palo alto bikes in the early to mid 80's

see [catalog](http://velobase.com/CatalogScans/Palo%20Alto%20Shop%20Catalogs/palo_alto_1984.pdf), it looks Biemmezeta frame built by palo alto bikes

Comment: The trim is slightly different on the Palo Alto bikes (on the top of the fork, seat stays, etc.), but Palo Alto did use Biemmezeta for their frames.

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]
My frame is 1984 Palo alto biemazeta. Dove looks right...Columbus tubing..reinforce tube...after 85' they started making the tucked t bolt nut for brake calipers.   I had too drill mine too fit ...trade e mails got pics of a repaint , new parts. Weighs in 19 lbs.
Thanks CB